# IE8 and font-face printing issues

Tags: printing, internet-explorer-8, font-face

I am encountering a weird problem when printing a site using IE8. The problem occurs after the print (or print-preview) dialog box closes, the web page goes entirely blank (white) even though the page prints fine. Refreshing fixes the issue.

I have recently included a print stylesheet which has @font-face declarations. Removing the @font-face declarations stops the issue from occurring. My font-face declarations are as follows:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'FONT';
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    src: url('../fonts/FONT.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/FONT.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
         url('../fonts/FONT.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
         url('../fonts/FONT.ttf') format('truetype'); /* Safari, Android, iOS */
}
```

I've tested this in IE7, IE8, IE9 and recent versions of Safari, Chrome & Firefox. The problem only happens in IE8.

Has anyone else experienced this and know a solution?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issues as you.  Got lucky and found out that the issue is caused by the relative path in the urls of your font files!  To fix your IE8 page-goes-blank problem after print or print preview, just replace your relative '../fonts/FONT.eot' paths with absolute paths.  In my case, we keep our fonts in /inc/css/fonts.  So I would update my url paramters to something like

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'FONT';
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    src: url('/inc/css/fonts/FONT.eot');
    src: url('/inc/css/fonts/FONT.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
         url('/inc/css/fonts/FONT.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
         url('/inc/css/fonts/FONT.ttf') format('truetype'); /* Safari, Android, iOS */
}
```

Again, I had the same problem as you where the issue only happens in IE8 (compat mode off).  It's a problem we had to solve because, even as of August 2012, 40% of our web users are still in IE8. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks heaps for the suggestion - will try it out!